# Pandas / Plot.plt Line Graph, X Values horizontal

Tags: pandas, plot, linegraph

How can I pass an argument to show all of the x value so one could read it? As well, how can I show many lines of data, and with  alegend?

```
plt. plot(a, b, linewidth=2.0 )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could display only `n-th` x-ticks and make a plot bigger to accomodate more labels.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(10), index=pd.Series(np.random.rand(10)).astype(str)+'_index')
                               0
0.007017115173211574_index  0.963285
0.434969747965131_index     0.547248
0.18021258326382017_index   0.719402
0.7815848046772174_index    0.061448
0.8856299613744312_index    0.771062
0.16840431221766328_index   0.524256
0.8662531211345982_index    0.528706
0.6389453277004077_index    0.287410
0.7444490769967744_index    0.513631
0.8965709043061524_index    0.892011

plt.subplots(figsize=(20,15)) # make plot bigger
plt.plot(df.index, df[0]*2, linewidth=.9) # plot several lines
plt.plot(df.index, df[0].rename('1'),linewidth=.9) # plot several lines
plt.xticks(df.index[::2]) # tick every 2nd label on x axis.
plt.legend() # show legend
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean? @pes04

Comment: @ hellpander look at the image I put into your code, I want the x axis values to show as that image does

Comment: You want a bar chart?

Comment: not concerned about the chart type. Just the xtick values ( notice how my first post they were horiztonal, I want them vertical, like the second image)